# Как вычислить координаты 4 точек, чтобы на карте получился квадрат?

Tags: математика, карты, map, яндекс-карты, картография

Суть проблемы в том, чтобы построить соты из шестиугольников на карте. столкнулся с тем, что даже квадраты построить не получается =( т.к. широта отличается от долготы.

Comment: все зависит от проекции, которую использует Ваша карта, если это проекция меркатора, то коэффициент, на который нужно умножать долготу зависит от широты

Comment: какая у Вас проекция?

Comment: Хм, а вы глобус видели?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я честно говоря дилетант в картах. Карты YandexMAP

Comment: @RuslanMirzapulatov я не знаю точно какая проекция у Яндекс карт, во все же полагаю что так называемая `Web Mercator`, тогда надо разделить `долготу` на `Math.cos(широта*Math.PI/180)`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ спасибо большое, попробую

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В зависимости от используемой географической проекции фигуры на карте будут выглядеть по разному.

Яндекс карты используют проекцию `Web Mercator`.

Эта проекция вносит искажения, чем дальше от экватора, тем больше искажение широты относительно долготы.

В этом случае, чтобы стороны прямоугольника, длины которых Вы задаете в градусах широты и долготы, выглядели квадратом в проекции `WebMercator`, необходимо чтобы они находились в соотношении:

```
 широта  — долгота
cos(lat) —    1
```

В сниппете ниже область, задаваемая на карте выглядит квадратом, при этом находится на разных широтах:

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  mapWithRect("map1", 60, 30, 0.01)
  mapWithRect("map2", 49, -123, 0.01)
});

function mapWithRect(id, lat, lon, size){

    let merc = Math.cos(lat*Math.PI/180);

    new ymaps.Map(id, {
        center: [lat, lon],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: []
    }).geoObjects.add(new ymaps.GeoObject({
        geometry: {
            type: 'Rectangle',
            coordinates: [
                [lat-size*merc, lon-size],
                [lat+size*merc, lon+size]
            ]
        }
    }))

}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
} 

#map1, #map2 { 
display:inline-block;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map1"></div><div id="map2"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Яндекс.Карты по умолчанию всё же используют не веб-Меркатор (сферическая проекция), а [эллиптическую проекцию Меркатора](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/projection.wgs84Mercator-docpage/?from=SO). Если хочется использовать именно сферическую проекцию, это надо [явно указать при создании карты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/?from=SO#Map__param-options.projection_modal).