# Покрытие карты сотами

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Пытаюсь покрыть небольшую часть карты полигонами в виде сот(правильными шестиугольниками), но столкнулся с проблемой отображения. Шестиугольники получаются вытянутыми:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример координат для данной соты:

```
[[[53.934177, 34.104857919243116], 
[53.934177, 34.22032797308104], 
[54.034177, 34.278063], 
[54.134177, 34.22032797308104], 
[54.134177, 34.104857919243116], 
[54.034177, 34.047122892324154], 
[53.934177, 34.104857919243116]]]
```

Я правильно понимаю, что это проблема с проекцией? Не до конца разобрался в данном вопросе, но как понял Яндекс использует проекцию Меркатора. Если да, то могу ли я преобразовать эти координаты, что бы получить правильный шестиугольник? Или же это проблема моего алгоритма и я неправильно генерирую соты?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1001747/188366 я полагаю Вы это ищите

Comment: я бы попробовал равномерно расставить по карте точки и построить для них диаграмму Вороного

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я правильно понимаю, что для того, чтобы преобразовать данный полигон в правильный шестиугольник, нужно изменить широты `j[0] = j[0]*math.cos(j[0]*math.pi/180)`?

Comment: Вы как получили эти точки? Брали 6 точек на окружности?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ [вот так](https://gist.github.com/urschrei/17cf0be92ca90a244a91)

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@larsvers/making-a-tesselated-hexbin-map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Нашел центр соты
2. Посчитал коэффициент проекции меркатора для центра.
3. Для каждой точки посчитал дельту от центральной по широте и пересчитал широту
   умножив эту дельту на коэффициент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var polygon = [
  [53.934177, 34.22032797308104], 
  [54.034177, 34.278063], 
  [54.134177, 34.22032797308104], 
  [54.134177, 34.104857919243116], 
  [54.034177, 34.047122892324154], 
  [53.934177, 34.104857919243116]
]

var center = polygon.reduce((acc, val) => [
  acc[0] + val[0]/polygon.length,
  acc[1] + val[1]/polygon.length
], [0, 0]);

var merc = Math.cos(center[0]*Math.PI/180); 

polygon.forEach(pt => pt[0] = center[0] + (pt[0] - center[0])*merc)

ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var map = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: center,
    zoom: 10
  });
  map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Polygon([
        polygon
  ]));
}
```

```css
html,body,#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не подскажите как в данном случае изменяется [сдвиг](https://imgur.com/a/h543HlG)?

Comment: я так же попробую попозже, центр соты следующей строки лежит на на линии продолжающей нижнее ребро

Comment: Как я понял сдвиг тоже [меняется](https://imgur.com/a/b1E4nkq) в зависимости от широты

Comment: @Steve да, все верно, надо считать от центров шестигранников прошлого ряда центры следующего, на малом масштабе это менее заметно, как Вы понимаете